# Retrieving suggestions from solr returns an empty set using django-haystack

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I have a web application written in Django and I am trying to use Django-haystack to communicate with solr. I have a searchComponent configured in solrconfig.xml as follows:

```
  <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="field">title_autocomplete</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
      <float name="threshold">0.0</float>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

I also have a requestHandler configured as follows:

```
  <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest/select">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

I have two haystack connection configs as follows:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection',
        'TIMEOUT': 5*60,
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
        'BATCH_SIZE': 1000
    },
    'suggestions': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection/suggest/',
        'TIMEOUT': 5*60,
        'BATCH_SIZE': 1000
    },
}
```

When I try to access the "suggest/select" request handler, it works normally over curl. I simply do `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/suggest/select?q=query`. However, when I try to query from haystack, I always get an empty result set.

```
SearchQuerySet(using='suggestions').filter(content=query) # => []
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Also, I want to know if there's a way to choose a request handler for handling my request. It appears that the way to do that is to just name handlers as handler/select and have a different connection config for every handler.

EDIT:

I resorted to doing quite a dirty hack. I basically used the search method of SolrSearchBackend. I had to make sure that INCLUDE_SPELLING was set to True in my settings. The problem is that the number of spelling suggestions is by default 1, and you can't change it as far as I know, so I also had to override the build_search_kwargs method.

This is what I have:

```
from haystack.backends.solr_backend import SolrSearchBackend

class SolrSuggest(SolrSearchBackend):

    def __init__(self, connection_alias, **connection_options):
        super(SolrSuggest, self).__init__(connection_alias, **connection_options)

    def build_search_kwargs(self, query_string, spellcheck_count=10):

        kwargs = {}
        kwargs['spellcheck.count'] = spellcheck_count
        return kwargs
```

After that I just get the suggestions using the following:

```
result = SolrSuggest('suggestions', **settings.HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS['suggestions']).search(query)
suggestions = []
if result.get('spelling_suggestion') and result.get('spelling_suggestion').get('suggestion'):
    suggestions = result.get('spelling_suggestion').get('suggestion')
```

This makes the spellcheck.count=10 by default.

I still think there's a simpler solution, so any suggestions would be awesome.